# Visual Studio 2017 no longer lets me triple click

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio-2017

I've used VS for over a year and I've always been able to triple click to select an entire line. Recently, something got screwed up and it no longer selects the line. It's driving me absolutely insane, because VS should have this functionality:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649222/4836298
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732098/visual-studio-is-there-a-keyboard-combination-to-select-an-entire-line/39922480#39922480

I looked through settings and can't find anything that could toggle this on or off.  Keyboard shortcuts don't apply to mouse functions as far as I can tell. Help?

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled, checked mouse/keyboard shortcuts, but to no avail.